# Cache the connection to Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, connection, azure-storage

In the article [How to use the Windows Azure Blob Storage Service in .NET](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) the following code is used to demonstrate how one might upload a file

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

If you had a long running service that was accepting files and storing them in blob storage would you perform all of these steps every time? Or would you maybe have a class that had a reference to `blockBlob` that was used by multiple requests? How much (if any) of this is it okay to cache and use from multiple requests? (which I guess means threads)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those objects have pretty light weight constructors and are not guaranteed to be thread safe (check the MSDN documentation) so I wouldn't be too concerned about caching them.  The only one I tend to keep as a static object is the cloud storage account.

Answer (score 5):

I concur with @knightpfhor, there is nothing to cache.  Until you call UploadFromStream, no long-running transactions have been called.  Everything is in memory, constructing objects.

This is not like a Sql Connection, where programmers would find clever ways to cache connections because they were expensive to open - this is REST calls, so every data-changing action is an https call and all the preparation prior to it, is simply light-weight object manipulation